# Magento - Create Shared Cookies to another URL

Tags: php, magento

All

Now, i have rewrite my website restriction module. when a user want to visit the website, have to click yes, then the user can be redirected to homepage, while generating my website's cookie. Now i get a requirement. when the user click 'yes' button, the browser will generate another website, url's cookie. then the user can directly visit that website, without clicking yes button twice. any one has any idea, about how the magento works for this?

Comment: Not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought this was not possible. However from reading @benmarks link above I found this link:

[How Facebook Sets and Uses Cross-Domain Cookies](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2010/08/how-facebook-sets-and-uses-cross-domain-cookies/)http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2010/08/how-facebook-sets-and-uses-cross-domain-cookies/

So it seems that there is some means to offer cross-domain cookies, as any cookies set outside of an iframe are accessible from within the iframe. Reality is though, it's far from perfect.

Try putting an iframe on website1 that loads a page on website2. have website2 then set it's own cookies, based on the value of the first cookie.

Good luck.